# CSS, how to set the layout

Tags: html, css

I have the following code to show a table

```
<div class="topologyBalloon" id="bl_c2f03b99-6d62-43c4-9a35-4b4cbf22a7db"> 
  <a href="#close" class="closeTopologyBalloon">×</a>
  <div class="contentBody">

    <table class="detailInfoTable">
      <caption>private</caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="device">ID</th>
          <td>c2f03b99-6d62-43c4-9a35-4b4cbf22a7db</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="device">status</th>
          <td>
            <span class="active">ACTIVE</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="detailInfoTable">
      <caption>subnets</caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <span title="cc59732b-4ce8-4aae-bab5-fac80c135440">
              <a href="/dashboard/project/networks/subnets/cc59732b-4ce8-4aae-bab5-fac80c135440/detail">cc59732b-4ce8-4aae-bab5-fac80c135440</a>
            </span>
          </th>
          <td>10.10.10.0/24</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
          <th>
            <span title="4394b976-f98c-4696-8348-5f6c78a8987e">
              <a href="/dashboard/project/networks/subnets/4394b976-f98c-4696-8348-5f6c78a8987e/detail">4394b976-f98c-4696-8348-5f6c78a8987e</a>
            </span>
          </th>
          <td>10.10.11.0/24</td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footerInner">
      <div class="cell link">
        <a href="/dashboard/project/networks/c2f03b99-6d62-43c4-9a35-4b4cbf22a7db/detail">» check detail information</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS file

```
table, th, td{
  border: 0px solid blue;
}

caption {
    font-weight: bold;
}

th {
    color: #D0D0D0;
}

.active {
    display:block;
    margin-right:5px;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:9px;
    height:9px;
    background-color:#ff6f0b
}
```

The output looks like this[image]

How can I indent the table and make a line to separate the tow table? The following are the output

[image]

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Or better create Snippet here but with better replica of what you are facing issue of.

Comment: I would seriously consider not using the `table` tag as you are not dealing with tabular data. Moving away from tables will give you more flexibility and is more suited to responsive design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```css
table, th, td{
  border: 0px solid blue;
}

caption {
    font-weight: bold;
}

th {
    color: #D0D0D0;
}

.active {
  display:block;
}
.active::before {
  content: " ";
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:10px;
  width:9px;
  height:9px;
  background-color:#ff6f0b;
  margin-right:5px; 
}
.topologyBalloon {
  background: #fff;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.topologyBalloon:before,
.topologyBalloon:after {
  content:"";
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;   
  border-right:10px solid #fff; 
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index:2;
}
.topologyBalloon:after {
  border-right-color:#ccc;
  left:-11px;
  z-index:1;
}
.closeTopologyBalloon {
  float: right; 
}
caption {
  text-align: left;
}
.detailInfoTable {
  border-bottom :1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.detailInfoTable td {
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topologyBalloon" id="bl_c2f03b99-6d62-43c4-9a35-4b4cbf22a7db"> 
  <a href="#close" class="closeTopologyBalloon">×</a>
  <div class="contentBody">
    <table class="detailInfoTable">
      <caption>private</caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="device">ID</th>
          <td>c2f03b99-6d62-43c4-9a35-4b4cbf22a7db</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="device">status</th>
          <td>
            <span class="active">ACTIVE</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="detailInfoTable">
      <caption>subnets</caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <span title="cc59732b-4ce8-4aae-bab5-fac80c135440">
              <a href="/dashboard/project/networks/subnets/cc59732b-4ce8-4aae-bab5-fac80c135440/detail">cc59732b-4ce8-4aae-bab5-fac80c135440</a>
            </span>
          </th>
          <td>10.10.10.0/24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <span title="4394b976-f98c-4696-8348-5f6c78a8987e">
              <a href="/dashboard/project/networks/subnets/4394b976-f98c-4696-8348-5f6c78a8987e/detail">4394b976-f98c-4696-8348-5f6c78a8987e</a>
            </span>
          </th>
          <td>10.10.11.0/24</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footerInner">
      <div class="cell link">
        <a href="/dashboard/project/networks/c2f03b99-6d62-43c4-9a35-4b4cbf22a7db/detail">» check detail information</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you need something like this:

```css
table, th, td{
  border: 0px solid blue;
}

caption {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left
}

th {
    color: #D0D0D0;
}


.active::before {
  content: " ";
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:10px;
  width:9px;
  height:9px;
  background-color:#ff6f0b;

}
```

```html
<div class="topologyBalloon" id="bl_c2f03b99-6d62-43c4-9a35-4b4cbf22a7db"> 
  <a href="#close" class="closeTopologyBalloon">×</a>
  <div class="contentBody">

    <table class="detailInfoTable">
      <caption>private</caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="device">ID</th>
          <td>c2f03b99-6d62-43c4-9a35-4b4cbf22a7db</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="device">status</th>
          <td>
            <span class="active">ACTIVE</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
<HR/>
    <table class="detailInfoTable">
      <caption>subnets</caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <span title="cc59732b-4ce8-4aae-bab5-fac80c135440">
              <a href="/dashboard/project/networks/subnets/cc59732b-4ce8-4aae-bab5-fac80c135440/detail">cc59732b-4ce8-4aae-bab5-fac80c135440</a>
            </span>
          </th>
          <td>10.10.10.0/24</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
          <th>
            <span title="4394b976-f98c-4696-8348-5f6c78a8987e">
              <a href="/dashboard/project/networks/subnets/4394b976-f98c-4696-8348-5f6c78a8987e/detail">4394b976-f98c-4696-8348-5f6c78a8987e</a>
            </span>
          </th>
          <td>10.10.11.0/24</td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footerInner">
      <div class="cell link">
        <a href="/dashboard/project/networks/c2f03b99-6d62-43c4-9a35-4b4cbf22a7db/detail">» check detail information</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```